# Query to find if there are more than X occurences within any period of given length minutes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, gaps-and-islands

I have spent many hours thinking about a solution for my problem but I give up.

Let's imagine a table

```
user_id | occurred_at
   -- OK match example
   1    | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 <- First match of the set
   1    | 2020-01-01 08:08:00 <- Second match (8 minutes away from the previous so OK)
   1    | 2020-01-01 08:10:30 <- this already exceeds 10 minutes period so the set is excluded

   -- Not matched example
   1    | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 <- First match
   1    | 2020-01-01 10:05:00 <- Second match (5 minutes away from the previous so OK)
   1    | 2020-01-01 10:09:59 <- this fits into 10 minutes period so the set is matched (09:59 away altogether from 10:00:00)

   -- Another OK (4 matched)
   2    | 2020-01-01 14:23:00
   2    | 2020-01-01 14:24:00
   2    | 2020-01-01 14:26:00
   2    | 2020-01-01 14:27:00

   -- Not matched
   3    | 2020-01-01 11:00:00
   3    | 2020-01-01 11:01:00
   3    | 2020-01-01 15:26:00
   3    | 2020-01-01 18:00:00

   -- User mismatch so set is not matched neither
   3    | 2020-01-01 20:00:00
   1    | 2020-01-01 20:01:00
   2    | 2020-01-01 20:02:00
```

How one can query a table like this to find rows with at least **N (=3 in this example)** occurrences for the given user that occurred in a explicit **minutes interval (=10 in this example)**? I think a table example above explains it better.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54d43/1

Comment: What do you want to find *exactly*? Whether a single given `user_id` has matching entries? (Or how many?) Or find all `user_id` that have at least one matching set of rows? Also, a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement would be nice for testing convenience. And *always* your version of Postgres, please. Oh, and don't use the misleading name `date` for a `timestamp` column.

Comment: Also, is there a `users` table with one row per `user_id`? That would be helpful in the event you want to identify all users that pass the test.

Comment: My bad. Fixed all your mentions. Yes there would be users table too but basically my main problem is to partition by those 10 minutes intervals. In other words what I need to find is if there was any user who has at least 3 timestamps assigned to him/her within a given period of minutes (10). This period can be anytime in a day. They just must fit 10 minutes period.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for your reply. I had a feeling it could be lag/lead but those are new concepts for me and time is chasing ;) I am going to play with it with tomorrow cause it is a middle of a night here where I am and I am exhausted after today's querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [window function `lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) we can mark all rows where a qualifying set ends:

```
SELECT *
     , occurred_at - lag(occurred_at, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY occurred_at) <= interval '10 min' AS passed
FROM   timestamps
ORDER  BY user_id, occurred_at;
```

*If the timestamp `occurred_at` for the same user (`user_id`) two rows back is within 10 minutes, we have a set of three.*

For a **given `user_id`**:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE passed) AS qualifying_sets
FROM (
   SELECT occurred_at - lag(occurred_at, 2) OVER (ORDER BY occurred_at) <= interval '10 min' AS passed
   FROM   timestamps
   WHERE  user_id = 1  -- given user
   ) sub;
```

To get **all `user_id`** that pass the test at least once:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) FILTER (WHERE passed) AS qualifying_sets
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
        , occurred_at - lag(occurred_at, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY occurred_at) <= interval '10 min' AS passed
   FROM   timestamps
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING bool_or(passed)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The added count of `qualifying_sets` is optional.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fa6bdd0c49c4ce964fce0fcb10654ab2)*

Comment: thanks a lot! Awesome function (lag). By the way, is it possible to achieve the same with postgresql versions not having lag() function?

Comment: That would be Postgres 8.3 or older. [Postgres 8.3 reached EOL in February 7, 2013](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). (!) There is always a way, but why raise the dead?